# IMG SRC inside PHP with more PHP inside how to

Tags: php, mysql

I always have trouble mixing languages and I recently started with MYSQL. In this case I have this code:

```
<?php
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Badges") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=".$info['Website'] . ""; 
 } 
?>
```

And I need it to print an image instead of the link it's printing.

http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=".$info['Website'] . " being the image's url

How would that be written? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print '<img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=' . $info['Website'] . '" alt="" />';
```

Some other tips...

- `mysql_*` are old functions, PDO is much better to use now it is available.
- `or die()` is old too - have you considered exceptions?
- `echo` is more commonly used than `print`, and you should use the case that is stated in the manual, e.g. `print` instead of `Print`.
- You should learn about separation of concerns, e.g. you should do your query and data management on a different layer where you pass the relevant data to your view which would consist solely of HTML and some PHP constructs used to generate it.

Comment: thanks, I'll check on all that. I just started with databases today!

Answer (score 0):

i usually find it easier to try and express what differs from case to case in an abstract manner. in your case it's the website (after `?domain=`) that differs, all the rest is the same. so the url to the image could abstractly be expressed as `http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={website}` where {website} is a place holder for future replacement.

replacement would then be performed using the function

```
$result = str_replace($what_to_replace, $what_to_replace_with, $original_string);
```

the advantage of this is that you're never mixing languages on one line, and this makes the code easier to develop :) just look at this quite easily read piece of code:

```
<?php
    $img = '<img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={website}" />';
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Badges") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    {
        $concrete_img = str_replace("{website}", $info['Website'], $img);
        print $concrete_img; 
    }
?>
```